# lazy load for dynamic component test coverage

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-testing-library

I have appRoutes.js file

```
import projectConfig from './projectConfig'
import React, {lazy} from 'react'
const Busin = lazy(() => import('./busine'))
const own = lazy(() => import(()=>import('./own'))

export const appRoutes = [{
   path: projectConfig.route, component: Busin},
  {path: projectConfig.route, component: own}]
```

own.js

```
import React from 'react'
const own = () => {
  return <div>
    <form>some child component</form>
 </div>
}
export default own
```

appRoute.test.js

```
import {render, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react'

describe('test', () => {
   it('lazy', () => {
      const {getByText} = render(<appRoutes />)
      await waitfor(() => {
         expect(getByText('').tobeinthedocument()
      })
   })
})
```

How can I cover the lazy load component here in the test coverage

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are re-assigning the `container` returned by `render`, I think your test should be:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {render, waitFor, getByText } from 'react-testing-library'
import AppRoutes from 'AppRoutes'

test('renders lazy component', async () => {
    const { container } = render(<appRoutes />)
    await waitFor(() => expect(getByText(container, 'I am lazy !' )).toBeInTheDocument())
})
```